# Create array of table cell values jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following code, which I'm using to create an array of all the tr's in the tbody area of a table.

```
var $table = $('#mytable');
var $rows = $table.find("tbody tr");
```

It works fine and contains the data from the table.  However, I want to loop over each row and create an array of the value of each cell in that row.  I've tried:

```
for(x=0;x<$rows.length;x++)
{
    var aCells = $rows[x].find("td");
    alert(aCells.length);
}
```

But the console is showing an error stating that Object # has no method 'find'

Can anyone help me?  I just want to loop over each row in the tbody one at a time and create an array of the cell values within that row so I can access a specific cell on each loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This returns DOM not a jQuery object

```
$rows[x]
```

You want to use [`eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/)

```
$rows.eq(x).find("td");
```

or just use each()

```
$rows.each(function(){
    var cells = $(this).find("td");
});
```

Comment: Worked like a charm!!  Thank you!  Will mark as correct answer as soon at it lets me.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.each()` to iterate through the `rows` and you can access its `td` elements by using the `$(this)` reference.

Try

```
$rows.each(function(){
    var aCells = $(this).find("td");
    alert(aCells.length);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

`$rows` is not an array. It's a jQuery object. Use `$rows.eq(x)` instead.
See the documentation of [.eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq/)

Comment: Thanks lex82, I wasn't aware of the .eq() method so thank you for your response.